# What are the Hero's outs?

Tags: texas-hold-em

In the following hand,

Hero: JA
Villain: 55
Board: 5,6,T

What are the outs for the Hero Or is the Hero drawing dead? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show the suits, so it's possible there may be outs to a flush as well. In general, Hero would need a king and queen on the turn and river, which would give him a straight to win the hand.

Comment: wouldn't JJ and AA also be useful here?  (and yes, flush draws are unknown with the info given...)

Comment: @joe no, as they would give villain a full house.

Comment: whoops, thanks!